# Error : Cannot find or open the PDB file error in in VS C ++ 2010

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I recently tried to do a camera calibration using c++ and openCV given the source code found on this link http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#source-code

but when i debug it it gave many erros like

```
cannot find or open PDB file
```

and

```
'Native has exited with code -1
```

What can i do to avoid these errors?

```
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\jay\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_calib3d248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_core248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_flann248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_imgproc248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_features2d248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui248.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'ConsoleApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[3836] ConsoleApplication1.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the files in Windows/System, not much. You are unlikely to have or need debugger symbols for them. Just don't try to step into them.

For the others, you need to build from source code in debug mode in order to get the PDB symbol files. if you don't have them, you can't debug them. This is probably a problem with your project file.

The final error is probably unrelated. The errors don't stop anything running, they just stop you debugging.

Comment: does my way of installing openCV has something to do with these errors? i always saw on tutorials that they use CMake to install openCV but i opt in installing openCV alone without using CMake because it takes long and its complicated.

Comment: Sorry, can't help. If you want to know that you might have to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

'Native has exited with code -1' means that the program (i.e. `main`) returned -1.

In other words, look for `return -1;` in your `main`.

The "pdb" errors are normal when you don't have access to debugger symbols for a DLL.

Comment: ok.. i will go over that.. how can i have access to these debugger symbols?

Comment: @user3388464 You're unlikely to ever need them. If you really want to, OpenCV can be built with symbols, but the ones from Microsoft aren't available for mere mortals like us.